# Working with a Binding to a collection in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, generics, swiftui

I'm trying to build a TextField that takes its value from a collection, much like

```
Toggle<C>(
    _ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey,
    sources: C,
    isOn: KeyPath<C.Element, Binding<Bool>>
) where C : RandomAccessCollection
```

I've build to following:

```
struct MultiTextField<C, V, F>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection,
                                            F: ParseableFormatStyle,
                                            V == F.FormatInput,
                                            F.FormatOutput == String {
    let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: KeyPath<Binding<C.Element>, Binding<V>>
    let format: F

    @State private var value: V?

    var body: some View {
        TextField(titleKey,
                  value: $value,
                  format: format)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print($sources.projectedValue[keyPath: keyPath])
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    struct Test {
        var value: Double
    }
 
    @State var sources = [Test(value: 0.1234),
                          Test(value: 2.3456)]

    return MultiTextField(titleKey: "Test",
                          sources: $sources,
                          keyPath: \.value,
                          format: .number)
}
```

The textfield on its own works, but I need to couple the result of the collection/keyPath to the value that the textfield uses. When the textfield is submitted or looses focus I want to write the value back to the collection (if it is valid (!=nil)).

I can't figure out how to do anything useful with the collection and the key path, hence I don't know how to continue here. The `print` statement as shown here gives a compile error: `Key path of type 'KeyPath<Binding<C.Element>, Binding<V>>' cannot be applied to a base of type 'Binding<C>'`

If I change the `keyPath` to a root type of `Binding<C>`, then I get an error in the preview that `[Test]` has no dynamic member `value`.

The best I could come up with is a `keyPath` of type: `WritableKeyPath<C.Element, V>`. That allows we to perform a map on `sources` and extract a useful value, but it doesn't allow me to actually update all values in the array to the new value.

How can I make use of the collection and the key path? How does `Toggle` access its `sources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, just a couple little changes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiTextField<C, V, F>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection,
                                           C.Element : Identifiable, //Add Identifiable for the ForEach
                                           F: ParseableFormatStyle,
                                           V == F.FormatInput,
                                           F.FormatOutput == String {
    let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: KeyPath<Binding<C.Element>, Binding<V>> 
    let format: F
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($sources, id:\.id){ $source in //C is a collection so you need a ForEach
            TextField(titleKey,
                      value: $source[keyPath: keyPath],
                      format: format)
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    struct Test: Identifiable{
        var id: UUID = .init()
        var value: Double
    }
    
    @State var sources = [Test(value: 0.1234),
                          Test(value: 2.3456)]
    
    return MultiTextField(titleKey: "Test",
                          sources: $sources,
                          keyPath: \.value,
                          format: .number)
}
```

If you want all the sources to match 1 TextField you can make them match when the value changes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MultiTextField<C, V, F>: View where C: RandomAccessCollection & MutableCollection & Equatable,
                                           C.Element : Identifiable & Equatable, //Add Identifiable for the ForEach
                                           F: ParseableFormatStyle,
                                           V == F.FormatInput,
                                           V: Equatable,
                                           F.FormatOutput == String {
    let titleKey: LocalizedStringKey
    @Binding var sources: C
    let keyPath: WritableKeyPath<C.Element, V> //Binding == read/write so you need WritableKeyPath, KeyPath is read-only.
    let format: F
    
    @State private var value: V? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(titleKey,
                  value: $value,
                  format: format)
        .task {
            //Make an initial value
            value = sources.first?[keyPath: keyPath]
        }
        .task(id: value) {
            //Update all the items
            guard let value = value, sources.first?[keyPath: keyPath] != value else {return}
            print("changing all items \(value)")
            for index in sources.indices {
                print(index)
                sources[index][keyPath: keyPath] = value
            }
            assert(sources.allSatisfy({ item in
                item[keyPath: keyPath] == value
            }))
        }
        
        
    }
}
struct MultiTextFieldParentView: View {
    @State var sources = [Test(value: 0.1234),
                          Test(value: 2.3456)]
    
    var body: some View{
        MultiTextField(titleKey: "Test",
                       sources: $sources,
                       keyPath: \.value,
                       format: .number)
    }
}
struct Test: Identifiable, Equatable, Hashable{
    var id: UUID = .init()
    var value: Double
}
#Preview {
    MultiTextFieldParentView()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution similar to your second suggestion. I will just need to tweak it a bit so it shows a 'multiple values' indicator if not all values in the collection are the same, but I can take it from here.